# Java Selenium. Find element by text for certain xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find an xpath expression to use in:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPATH HERE"))).click();
```

The element says "Invite Users" on the page and i need to be able to click on it

I need to find the element `/a[@id='inviteUsers_8ef17ba4-b739-4fb6-8198-3862ea84c381_toggle']` but the problem is the characters after "inviteUsers_" is dynamically generated

I have already tried these:

```
"//*[contains(.,'Invite Users')]";
"//a[contains(.,'Invite Users')]";
```

And these give `NoSuchElement` exceptions.

This is the complete XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[@class='col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 main']/fieldset[@class='form-horizontal']/div[@id='roles']/div[@id='entitlements']/div[@class='panel panel-default '][3]/div[@id='service_8ef17ba4-b739-4fb6-8198-3862ea84c381']/div[@class='panel-body']/div[@class='panel panel-default'][1]/div[@class='panel-heading']/h4[@class='panel-title']/a[@id='inviteUsers_8ef17ba4-b739-4fb6-8198-3862ea84c381_toggle']
```

Comment: Did you find your answer? If not, please post the relevant HTML for the link you are trying to click.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with `starts-with()`:

```
//a[starts-with(@id, "inviteUsers_")]
```

Comment: Still failed to find the element unfortunately :( Am i missing something from the xpath ? Maybe i need to get a specific div before trying to access the element  ?

Comment: @shanwar no, if it fails like that, it would fail with a specific `div` as well. Is this a public page and you can share a link to it? Thanks.

Comment: Unable to do that sorry. Confidential page under development. Could it be that this element appears in sort of like a drop down area after a subsequent click of a previous element so it fails? I would think the wait (7sec before timeout) takes care of that...

Comment: @shanwar could be all sorts of things happening, difficult to say what is it exactly. Could you post how this element looks in the HTML? Also, make sure you make all the necessary actions for that element to appear.

Comment: Watching Selenium execute the test(with debugger) I can see that it execute until the point where it tries to find that element

Comment: <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a id="inviteUsers_8ef17ba4-b739-4fb6-8198-3862ea84c381_toggle"data-toggle="collapse" href="#inviteUsers_8ef17ba4-b739-4fb6-8198-3862ea84c381" >
                                                Invite Users
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>

Comment: @shanwar thanks. The XPath expression itself is correct and should match the element. What happens when you use the `wait.until()` to wait for it? Do you get an error? Which one?

Comment: This is the error i get: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 7 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[starts-with(@id, "inviteUsers_")]

Comment: @shanwar just a quick check - the element is not inside an iframe, right?

Comment: Negative. Just a inside a panel on the same page

Comment: @shanwar alright. What happens if you replace `visibilityOfElementLocated` with `presenceOfElementLocated`?

Comment: "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"
Weird since I can see the element physically appear on the page before this step

Comment: @shanwar awesome, we've got progress. So, we locate the element correctly, but it is invisible for selenium. Multiple things you can do to solve the element not visible error, please see this related topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871071/click-function-isnt-working-in-protractor-scripts/36940011#36940011, http://stackoverflow.com/a/37735942/771848, http://www.blaiseliu.com/protractor-error-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-xx-xx/. They are kind of Protractor specific, but I think you''ll be able to apply them to Java+Selenium.

Comment: Ok as per the link I implemented the scroll into view method with a helper class. If the element is located first get location with <element.getLocation()
Then using JavaScript executor API: je.executeScript("scroll(" + p.getX() + ", " + p.getY() + ");");

And then:
WebElement invite  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(inviteX)));
            scrollElementIntoViewAndClick(invite);

Comment: This still gives a me an Element is not visible exception

Comment: @shanwar...if you can find element but you could not `click` on it due to **element is not visible** then you should try to `click` on it using `JavaScriptExecutor` as like that :- `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", invite);`...may be it will work

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work try find a unique parent.

```css
//div[contains(@id, 'service')]//a[contains(@id, 'inviteUsers')]
```